# Can a commutator algebra be interpreted as a Turing machine?

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I'm building a tool for simplifying non-commutative expressions with the aid of a commutator algebra. The user can define any operator they like and specify commutation relations, then ask the computer to move all instances of a particular symbol to the right.

There are two kinds of object involved here - `Operator`s and `Expression`s. `Operator`s have no structure on their own, but `Expression`s  consist of any polynomial of `Operator`s.

An example calculation may read

```
Operator a
Operator b
Operator c

[a,b] <- a+a*c
[c,a] <- a

x = a*c*a*b

move_right( x, a)
# = acba + ac(a + ac)
# = caba - aba + caa - aa + caac - aac
# = cbaa + c(a+ac)a - baa - (a+ac)a + caa  -aa + caca - caa - aca + aa
# ...
==> +1 c b a a  -3 c a a  +2 c c a a  -1 b a a  +1 a a
```

In the commutator definition `[a,b] <- xpr`, the two entries `a,b` on LHS must be `Operator`, but the right hand side `xpr` may be any `Expression`.

Note that the "move right" command is applied recursively at each stage, so that the end result is guaranteed to end with the specified term.

It is easy to write down a non-terminating "simplification problem":

```
[a,b] <- a*b
move_right(a*b, a)
# = ba + ab
# = 2ba + ab
# = 3ba + ab
# ...
```

Clearly, this is not enough to qualify as a program, but it seems like the framework is sufficiently flexible that one could perform non-trivial indirect computations.

My question is:
**Can any algorithm be expressed in terms of commutation relations and successive calls to `move_right`, and if not, what additional operations are needed?**

Comment: In short : You ask whether your software is turing-complete.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm not an expert in computer science, so I don't know what to look for.